# EC2 Restore Snapshot BOTO3 lambda

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, restore, snapshot

I'm trying to find a way to create a lambda function to restore a snapshot EC2 with Python BOTO3.

Is there someone to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`create_volume()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_volume), specifying a `SnapshotId` to use as the source:

```py
response = client.create_volume(
    AvailabilityZone='string',
    SnapshotId='string',
    VolumeType='standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but when i implement my lambda as the followinf i received this error message:

import json
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ec2.create_volume(
    AvailabilityZone='eu-west-3a',
    SnapshotId='snap-061832fc7e98722c9',
    VolumeType='standard')
    return response
```

[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: ec2.Volume(id='vol-0d99ae0316d78481d') is not JSON serializable